# Safari Mobile experiencing strange spacing issues

Tags: css, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I am about to launch a new Joomla site, and the only minor bug holding me up (not really effecting launch, just annoying) is this strange issue with iPhone (using Safari Mobile). You can see it in the image attached or use http://synthphone.com/ to see it.

[image]

Any ideas? I haven't noticed any other issue on any other browser or device. Link to the page is http://www.complisolutions.com/services.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Are you talking about the space after `multi-media`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the weird spacing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a font size issue - note the word 'environmental' - looks to me like that cannot fit in the space allocated between the image and the left side of the screen.

Try remove that word to see if this is the case.

What you'll want to do, is use media queries to firstly make that image full page width at small screen resolutions and secondly to remove the float.

Comment: Thought that too, but scrolling down to the final picture, and everything fits! Odd, i'll give your suggestion a go, probably best anyway... thanks!